# Intel DH61BE windows server 2003 Drivers

Tags: drivers, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2003

I have Intel DH61BE board I couldn't find the windows server 2003 driver. Can any one give me a download link Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The DH61BE is a desktop board. [Read up!](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/19481/eng/Windows_Server_OS_support.pdf)

> ## Windows Server 2003* or 2008* Driver Availability for Intel® Desktop Boards
>
> Intel does not plan to develop and offer Windows Server 2003 or Windows Server 2008 drivers for any Intel® Desktop Board.

That said, you should be able to get away with using the Windows XP drivers.

Comment: xp drivers didn't do the trick

Comment: Okay well buy a server board :)